# Will ADS-B eventually replace TCAS antennas on airliners?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations, ads-b

I still seem to confuse myself about ADS-B. Will ADS-B eventually replace TCAS antennas on airliners? Or are those still a relevant part of the ADS-B system? And I guess just to add in, why don't smaller planes have TCAS antennas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The future replacement to TCAS II is called [ACAS X<sub>A</sub>](https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/acas-x). It uses ADS-B Out data along with the current TCAS II Mode S range and bearing to provide more accurate aircraft positioning, reducing the amount of false alerts and allowing better collision avoidance logic.

Initially, ACAS X<sub>A</sub> will utilize the same TCAS II antennas for backwards compatibility, however looking in future decades, removal of active TCAS II could conceivably take place.

Another version for is for general aviation, ACAS X<sub>P</sub>. It solely listens to ADS-B broadcasts and is in development. This doesn't work as well as full ACAS X<sub>A</sub>/TCAS II, but is much cheaper and intended for planes that aren't required to have TCAS II.

Answer (score 1):

ADS-B OUT - Your transponder talks to a ground facility and is combined.with other aircraft transponders and retransmitted from the ground facility to those aircraft having ADS-B IN.

TCAS - Your system is talking with other TCAS systems around you, a 'conversation' between the two systems conveys position, altitude and direction of flight between the aircraft and determines, jointly, if there is a collision imminent, the two systems will issue CLIMB or DESCENT orders to both pilots in order to resolve the conflict.

The two systems are for two very different uses and ADS-B is not capable of performing the collision avoidance between aircraft. Therefore ADS-B will not replace TCAS II.

Comment: "retransmitted from the ground facility to those aircraft having ADS-B IN." That's TIS-B and ADS-R. TIS-B broadcasts non-ADS-B traffic, and ADS-R bridges 1090ES to UAT. In situations where everybody is using ADS-B Out on 1090ES, no ground infrastructure is used. One example is in-trail procedures in oceanic airspace, where aircraft use ADS-B In to follow other aircraft at reduced sepration.

Comment: Would this mean that a TCAS equipped 737 would not warn the pilots of a ADS-B equipped Cessna 172?